# Extract names formatted with specific colors in different positions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have names and they have colors matching the color name itself. I want to extract these names referring to the colors I want. The problem is that they are in different positions, for example: How do I extract the characters in "Blue" ??[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this by using VBA. In Excel, you only can use the defined function to extract the text based on font color.

Just read the links below to review the code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514704/how-to-extract-text-based-on-font-color-from-a-cell-with-text-of-multiple-colors?rq=1

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2234-excel-extract-cell-color.html#a1